What does "it" refer to in the sentence?
In the sentence below:

32 Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY 10013-2473, USA


Cambridge University Press is part of the University of Cambridge.


It furthers the University’s mission by disseminating knowledge in the pursuit of
education, learning, and research at the highest international levels of excellence.


www.cambridge.org

Information on this title: www.cambridge.org/9780521809269


© Cambridge University Press, 1980, 1989, 2015

Does it refer to Cambridge University Press or by disseminating knowledge in the pursuit of education, learning, and research at the highest international levels of excellence?
Thank you in advance.

"By disseminating …" isn't a noun phrase. Only one of these is grammatically possible.

@the-baby-is-you I think that sentence can write as “By disseminating ... furthers the University’s mission”, maybe that's no problem.

If this is a quote, it would help to include the link. (I checked both links given, and neither has this wording.) Based on the wording in the question, it definitely refers to Cambridge University Press. Why do you think there is another possibility?

@PeterKirkpatrick Origin text form is like that I write. Because I see grammar book say if write “By disseminating ... furthers the University’s mission” form is not very good, so I think should let it place begin of sentence, just like: "To know that the bakery Ed is managing is not doing very well is sad", the "To know ... is sad" is right, but if spoken it, it is very hard to listen understand, so it will change to "it is sad to know that the bakery Ed is managing is not doing very well".

My advice: Don't be afraid to simplify. In your bakery examples, version 1 is correct, but I had to read it twice to understand it. Version 2 is simpler, clearer, and says exactly the same thing. I would always choose version 2.

@PeterKirkpatrick Yes, you said is right, so I understand “By disseminating ... furthers the University’s mission”  with bakery examples idea.

"It" is a pronoun. In basic terms it will refer backwards to a previously mentioned noun. So in this case it is the Cambridge University Press.
To clarify further, it's certainly possible for a pronoun to refer to a noun phrase such as disseminating knowledge. But the sentence would have to be significantly rewritten to mean this. For example:

Cambridge University's mission is the dissemination of knowledge... It is the primary responsibility of the Cambridge University Press.

Now the pronoun refers to [the mission which is] dissemination of knowledge, and cannot refer to the Cambridge University Press, which when we read the pronoun has not yet been mentioned.

Good explanation. Thank you very much.

That's three sentences!
Yes, it refers to Cambridge University Press, following on from what the previous sentence said about it.
Incidentally, the correct expression is In the sentence below (meaning 'written below this one').

Thank you for your answer, but I can't understand about"the correct expression is In the sentence below (meaning 'written below this one').". So can you say more clear?

Lots of English learners begin their questions with "In the below sentence..." or similar, because adjectives normally come before the noun. In fact the usual way to say it in English is "In the sentence below..."

I see. Thank you for your explanation. I will modify my question for correct it.
